# What is the complexity of this Prime finding algorithm?

Tags: python, algorithm, time-complexity, complexity-theory, primes

My dad and I are trying to determine the algorithmic complexity of this prime finding function that my dad came up with as a youngster.

The first loop is obviously n since it sets up the dictionary. The trickier part is the nested loops. The outer loop runs n/4 times: `0 to n/2, step=2`. The inner loop only runs if the number is considered prime which happens a lot at the beginning but happens less and less as the numbers increase.

```
def primesV2(n):
    count = 0 # count is for counting the number of iterations done

    # set all even numbers (and 1) to False, else assume prime
    x = {}
    for i in range(n):
        if (i != 2 and i % 2 == 0) or i==1:
            x[i] = False
        else:
            x[i] = True

    # start at 3 because its the first odd prime
    i=3
    while i < n/2: # loop until halfway to n
        if x[i]: # if the number is considered prime
            for j in range(3*i,n,i*2): # if i=3, j will be 9,15,21 (odd multiples of 3)
                x[j] = False # these are not prime
                count = count + 1
        else:
            count = count + 1
        i = i+2

    return x, count
```

Comment: This code does not run because of lacking indentation on line 8, and `KeyErrors` that happen at the first if statement in the while loop

Comment: This is a **less** efficient version of the usual optimised Sieve of Eratosthenes ... less efficient as eg it (i) loops to `n / 2` rather than `sqrt(n)`, and uses eg `range(3*i, ...)` in the sub-step versus `range(i*i, ...)`

Comment: @JacobIRR Fixed sorry the formatting was weird when taking it from my text editor.

Comment: As far as I know, the number of primes less than `n` is still `O(n)` (that is, there are `O(n)` many primes less than `n`), so your while loop is still `O(n^2)`. (there's some work on the asymptotic frequency of primes, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem))

Comment: Also, the implementation given here will be **very inefficient due to the use of a dictionary for storage**.  There is no reason not to use an array/list ...

Comment: @donkopotamus I don't know about very inefficient... Takes O(1) to insert into a dict and amortized O(1) to retrieve from a dict. Also not really the point of the exercise as its more to determine the algorithmic complexity of finding primes. Obviously a list would also work, instead of appending to a list, I decided to use the [i] notation (makes it easier for my dad).

Comment: @JonathanMongeau lists use `[i]` notation as well ... simply preallocate the list as `[False] * n`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have here is a modified Sieve of Eratosthenes. Without any optimizations the complexity would be `O(n log log n)`. Check out [this wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) article why that is.

Your optimizations speed it up by a total factor of 4. You only go up to n/2 (you could stop at `sqrt n`) and you skip half the multiples. While this will make the code faster the complexity remains unchanged (constant factors are ignored). So it will still be `O(n log log n)`.

Comment: If I changed it to be sqrt n would that not change the complexity? N/4 is O(n) but root(n) is O(n^1/2). Does that mean this algorithm is not O(n log n log n)?

Comment: The leading N comes from marking the multipliers (you are checking them in an array of size N). 'sqrt n' would change the number of prime numbers you need to mark. This goes into the `log log N` part. It would be `log log (n^1/2)` that is equal to `log (1/2 * log N)`  or `log 1/2 + log log N` so it becomes a constant and doesn't affect the complexity.